# How do I transfer the datasource for a viewTable from another swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this may sound very stupid, i've been trying for hours but couldn't figure out how. How do I load the titles to the tableView in this scenario?

I know there is an easy method where you can declare an array in the ViewController.swift file and make the delegate and datasource = self like this:

```
self.drugsTableView.dataSource = self
self.drugsTableView.delegate = self
```

But in this case i would like to get the tableView datasource from another swift file, here is how my scenario is going:

In the project navigator i have the following files:

**1. ViewController.swift**

**2. DrugsLibrary.swift**

**3. DrugList.swift**

> **ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var drugsTableView: UITableView!

var drugList: DrugsLibraryStruct?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.drugsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.drugsTableView.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.title = "Titles"

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DrugsLibraryStruct().drugsLibraryDictionary.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")
    return cell
}
```

> **DrugsLibrary.swift**:

```
import Foundation

struct DrugsLibraryStruct {

let drugsLibraryDictionary = [
    [
        "name": "Drug A",
        "subtitle": "Drug A subtitle!",
        "icon": "drugA.pdf"

    ],
    [
        "name": "Drug B",
        "subtitle": "Drug B subtitle",
        "icon": "drugb.pdf"
    ]
]
```

}

> **DrugList.swift**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct DrugListStruct {

var name: String?
var subtitle: String?
var icon: UIImage?

init(index: Int) {

    let drugsLibrary = DrugsLibraryStruct().drugsLibraryDictionary
    let drugListDictionary = drugsLibrary[index]

    name = drugListDictionary["name"] as String!
    subtitle = drugListDictionary["subtitle"] as String!

    let iconName = drugListDictionary["icon"] as String!
    icon = UIImage(named: iconName)
}
```

}

Here is the [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okfnk7z4hafc2qb/transfer2.zip?dl=0) on Dropbox

I would really appreciate your hints or help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another file.

```
class DataSource: NSObject {

    lazy var list ... //your data here
}

extension DataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    //method here
}

extension DataSource: UITableViewDelegate {
    //method here
}
```

and in your ViewController:

```
let dataSource = DataSource()

drugsTableView.dataSource = dataSource
drugsTableView.delegate = dataSource
```

Brace yourself, it will get tricky when you use `UITableViewDelegate` :)

---

Since you're new, I update my answer with more details.

`lazy var list` is your `dataArray`, you can remove the `lazy` part. I leave it there because I don't display my table immediately, so I don't query it until it's needed.

In your case, just use: `var myArray = ...`

```
extension DataSource: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView - numberOfRowsInsection (your method above)
    func tableView - cellForRowAtIndexPath (your method above)
    //these methods are required, since they're needed for display data on table
}

extension DataSource: UITableViewDelegate {
    //methods which will be called when you interact with the table
    func tableView - didSelectRowAtIndexPath ...
}
```

I don't have Xcode here, so find these methods yourself :)

If you want to use the `UITableViewDelegate`, you have to create a protocol, which is called inside these `UITableViewDelegate`'s methods and delegate them back to your controller :)

Comment: Thank you Pham, it sounds simple but for me it's too complicated since i'm very new to this, can you give me an example about the lazy var list? let's assume i'd like to have an array there. Also What about the methods? I have no idea what method should be used. Is it a way to iterate through the array? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I finally had it working, I used your code as a hint but I had to use a different code. Here's the code:

```
class Datasource: NSData, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let itemsArray = ["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"test")
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.itemsArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}